# How do you upgrade puppet on Apache / passenger on EL6.4?

Tags: redhat, puppet, puppetmaster, foreman

I have a Scientific Linux 6.4 server running apache / passenger with puppet-server installed. Also installed is Foreman 1.4. When I upgraded my agents to 3.4.2, they started all logging:
Using less secure serialization of reports and query parameters for compatibility
with older puppet master. To remove this notice, please upgrade your master(s) 
to Puppet 3.3 or newer.

So I looked at the server, and upgraded puppet-server to 
puppet-server-3.4.2-1.el6.noarch
I've restarted httpd (apache)...

Basically, the agents still complain. I've also updated puppet to 
puppet-3.4.2-1.el6.noarch
no luck...

I just want the agents to stop logging the warning every run...  Does the passenger not use the system installed rpm? I can't find any documentation on this, and Puppet IRC only gave me the suggestion to install puppet-server (I actually had not had that installed, and my server was working...)

Puppet user group hasn't answered me...

Thanks for any ideas...

Comment: How did you install foreman?

Comment: I used RPMs to install foreman

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to work this out down to a foreman misconfiguration. Full thread here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/wvBHZjzkQYI

Relevant ending:
And to fully close this out - I ended up with a strange configuration going from Foreman 1.1 -> 1.4 and Puppet 3.1.x -> 3.4.2...

In Passanger.conf

Change:

PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby193-ruby

To:

/usr/bin/ruby

And in the virtual host definitions add:
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby193-ruby

Comment: What was the misconfiguration and how did you fix it?

Comment: If you could add a short summary of what the misconfiguration was and how you fixed it, that would be very useful for anyone else having the same problem and looking for help here in the future.